# Requerying Text Fields Immediately after another Text Field Changes Value in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I am creating a form with multiple subforms. The way that it works is that:

1. the user selects a `BASIC` at the top
2. that makes the text fields `MACHINE NAME`, `TOOL SEQUENCE NO.`, `TOOL NO.`, and `TOOL DESCRIPTION` change.
3. The text fields `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` and `MACHINE TYPE` at the bottom depend on the `MACHINE NAME`, which means that
4. as soon as the machine name changes, the machine description and type should immediately change.

I used queries to describe the relationship between `BASIC` and `MACHINE NAME` and between `MACHINE NAME` and `MACHINE DESCRIPTION`.

What ends up happening is that when I change the `BASIC`, the `MACHINE NAME` changes but the `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` doesn't change immediately. The `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` changes only after the second time I change the `BASIC`  (and it changes to the `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` matching the `MACHINE NAME` selected previously).

I believe this is because the `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` waits until the `MACHINE NAME` is changed to requery the data, which would explain why the value for the machine description is "delayed" one click.

**How do I make the `MACHINE DESCRIPTION` change as soon as the `MACHINE NAME` changes?**

I am open to using VBA code if it is required.

[image: Form]

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is often known as a trigger language as it is often used in response to events in the application which for the MS Access object library includes `AfterUpdate`, `OnOpen`, `ButtonClick`, etc. in GUI objects such as forms and reports, and can even extend to called functions in macros and modules.

Because you have subforms showing "snapshot" resultsets to screen derived from queries with parameters pointing to form values, consider actually requerying subforms after saving your user entry with [Form.Requery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.requery) for newer "snapshots". In fact, it is a wonder *any* subform was updated without `Form.Requery`!

Place the below VBA code in an `AfterUpdate` event behind your *BASIC* textbox. Do not repeat `Public Sub` and `End Sub`. This will loop through all subforms using the [Forms.Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.controls) property of your main form after you update values in *BASIC* entry.

```
Private Sub BASIC_AfterUpdate()
     Dim ctrl As Control

     ' SAVE CURRENT RECORD
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord 

     ' REQUERY ALL SUBFORMS
     For Each ctrl in Me.Form.Controls
          If ctrl.Type = acSubform Then
              Me.Form.Controls(ctrl.Name).Form.Requery
          End If
     Next ctrl

     Set ctrl = Nothing
End Sub
```